# Зависимый фон Actionbar от другого цвета

Tags: java, android

Все никак не могу найти информацию. Как сделать цвет фона ActionBar`a от фона самого приложения. То есть ситуация: в моем приложении, можно сказать, есть 2 основных цвета. Я хочу сделать так, чтоб пользователь имел возможность выбирать их. Так вот, если он выберет, например, синий в качестве одного из них, aBar должен автоматически стать таким же, но чуть темнее. Выбрал красный - aBar стал красным, но темнее.
Я не могу найти как сделать такую - динамическую(если ее можно так назвать) - замену цвета элемента. Все, что гуглится - как просто в коде изменить цвет. А мне надо зависимость от другого.
Буду очень признателен, если кто-то подскажет как это можно сделать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта:

1. Создать свои стили где прописать все ваши цвета.
2. Программно сетить подобранные цвета.

С учетом того что вы не дали никакого кода, поэтому мне сложно понять  `надо зависимость от другого`. Поэтому вот как сделать стили (программно я так понял вы знаете как это делается):

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- This is the styling for action bar -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@color/red</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Вот есть [вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288402/how-to-set-custom-actionbar-color-style#:%7E:text=You%20can%20define%20the%20color,file%20of%20your%20Android%20project.&text=Then%20set%20%22MyCustomTheme%22%20as%20the,Activity%20that%20contains%20the%20ActionBar.) как создавать стили

[Вот есть документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) по созданию стилей и тем. [Туториал_1](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-styles-and-themes-with-examples), [туториал_2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-color-of-action-bar-in-an-android-app/) и [туториал_3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_styles_and_themes.htm)

Comment: Я наверно неправильно изъяснидся, когда писал. По сути, мне надо получить выбранный пользователем цвет приложения, _**"затемнить" его**_ и применить уже новый. Вот именно как "затемнить" его программно я и не знаю
Может быть СolorMatrix (а точнее ColorFilter в нем) мне в этом поможет, стараюсь сейчас разобраться как он работает